# how to handle on key press event on mobile mode . when key press on input type="text".. its work proper on desktop mode (key press by keyboard)

Tags: javascript

How to on keypress  event of javascript handle the validation of vechicle number in mobile mode .. not work properly.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="func1()" id="vname">
<script>
function func1()
{
alert('hello');
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="func1()" id="vname">
```

not alert the message on keypress of id="vname" in mobile but work proper in desktop mode ... and i also try the tap () of jquery mobile  but its also not works when touch the keyboard through enter the value in input tag

Comment: There’s really lots of questions regarding this issue already, https://www.google.com/search?q=keypress+equivalent+for+mobile+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Did the answer below suit your needs? Could you mark it as accepted if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

`keypress` is known to be troublesome in mobile environments. You should use `onkeydown`

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="func1()" id="vname">
<script>
function func1()
{
alert('hello');
}
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="func1()" id="vname">
```